# Complicated Schengen visa situation involving multiple trips and H1b visa!

Tags: schengen-visas, greece, h1b-visas

I am in the US on the H1B visa. I am planning a leisure trip to Greece in September. After this trip, I come back to the US. Later in October, I have a business trip (conferences) to Germany and Czech Republic. I will be spending most time in Greece.

An additional consideration is that my H1B will expire in December 2019. I am applying for an extension that will extend my ability to stay in the US to 2022 but I will not have the extended H1B stamp before I apply for the Schengen visa.

Given my situation, can I apply for a multiple entry Schengen visa at the Greece embassy?

I have heard that *some* consulates require 3 months on the US visa to approve a Schengen visa (which is not going to be possible in my case). Could I write the Greece embassy a cover letter explaining my situation?